# Access to the template file of a plug-in

Tags: plugin-development, rewrite-rules

I am developing a plugin that consists only of REST API queries.  It consists only of the `myplugin.php` and the template files (`index.php`, `style.css` & `functions.js`) and has no connection to the installed WP-theme.

The plugin should be accessible via the URL: `example.com/myplugin`, which I achieved with this entry in `plugin.php`:

```php
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule('myplugin', 'wp-content/plugins/myplugin/theme/index.php', 'top');
});
```

In the `index.php` I can unfortunately only include the two external scripts (.css, .js) via absolute path, because if I define a variable in `plugin.php`, it is not output in `index.php`.

How can I integrate the template (`index.php`) so that it has access to the previously defined variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe dirty, but it works:

```php
$slug = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$slug = explode('/', $slug);
$slug = array_filter($slug);
$slug = end($slug);
if ($slug == 'myplugin') {
    include(__DIR__.'/theme/index.php');
    exit;
}
```